# Subcriber callback within a while loop?

Tags: ros, c++, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible for a subscriber to make a callback within a while loop?...
if so how then..

In my case i am Subscribing to topic which giving me a position of a robot.
I have a array of 8 positions.

```
double position[8] = {2.0 , 3, 3.0, ...}
```

And in a while  in a loop, I make to robot walk to those position, one after one.
i

```
nt  i = 0
while(i<8)
{
    robotposition = position[i];
   if(real_position == robotposition){
    i++;
   }
}
```

Here is the real_position, the real position of the robot, which I receive from a callback function..
The problem here is though that this value doesn't get updated when it is in the while loop.. and i don't why.. how do i do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205321/subcriber-callback-within-a-while-loop?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Call ros::spinOnce() in the loop. That will cause callbacks to be called.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-03-18**:
I just love you <3